# Python : Text Replacement In Large Files

Tags: python

I'm trying to insert text at very specific locations in a text file. This text file can be fairly large (>> 10 GB)

The approach I am currently using to read it:

```
with open("my_text_file.txt") as f:
   while True:
     result = f.read(set_number_of_bytes)
     x = process_result(result)
     if x:
       replace_some_characters_that_i_just_read_and write_it_back_to_same_file
```

However, I am unsure as to how to implement

```
replace_some_characters_that_i_just_read_and write_it_back_to_same_file
```

Is there some method which I can use to determine where I have read up to in the current file that I might be able to use to write to the file.

Performance-wise, if I was to use the approach above to write to the original file at specific locations, would there be efficiency issues with having to find the write location before writing?

Or would you recommend creating an entirely different file and appending to that file on each loop above. Then deleting the original file after this operation is completed? Assuming space is not a large concern but performance is.

Comment: Is the text you replace exactly the same length as the original? If not, then you have little choice, and need to create a new file.

Comment: Not all of the text will be the same as the original. Does the fileinput module internally create a new file each time a write occurs (each iteration of the loop)? (mentioned below)

Comment: @user1431282: Expanded in my answer; the file is moved aside, and you write a complete new file with the original data altered as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html), which handles files correctly when replacing data, with the `inplace` flag set:

```
import sys
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('my_text_file.txt', inplace=True):
    x = process_result(line)
    if x:
        line = line.replace('something', x)

    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

When you use the `inplace` flag, the original file is moved to a backup, and anything your write to `sys.stdout` is written to the original filename (so, as a new file). Make sure you include all lines, altered or not.

You *have* to rewrite the complete file whenever your replacement data is not *exactly* the same number of bytes as the parts that you are replacing.